# Can Orchard CMS allow random internet people to register to my site?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm about to start a new commission project and I think Orchard CMS is a good fit for what they're asking. More or less, at this point I'm still looking at my options.

Does Orchard allow people to register on my site?

According to the [documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Managing-users-and-roles), it seems that only Administrators can create users and assign roles to them. If this is the case, I can't use Orchard.

Maybe I missed something in the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you missed is the user settings. There is a checkbox there to allow people to register to the site. The topic you linked to is about user administration, it says nothing about who can register.

Comment: This does not seem to be available under Orchard 1.7 (RC) Any idea where it is now?